# Thumbnail of exported render looks different

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, export

sooo, on the right you see the rendered PNG.
On the right you see the completely different looking thumbnail. So, basically I have two questions.
1: Why? Why does it look so different?
2: How do I get my actual render look like the thumbnail?

[image]

Comment: is the background of the smoke transparent?

Answer (score 1):

It could be something to do with how transparency/semi-transparency is displayed on the thumbnail of your PNG vs what it actually looks like.

In order for your smoke to look like that in the PNG, you'll need to make it thicker and have a bit more volume absorption. Possibly also a bit of vorticity/noise.

This is largely speculation as I don't know your setup for the smoke settings or the shader.